# How to view the methods of a particular object in Python IDLE?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, python-idle

Can we see the list of methods or variables of an Object by entering a dot '.' next to the Object?

eg.

```
self.label = QLabel()
self.label.  # can I get the methods list on entering the last '.' ?
```

I tried but for very few I got the list.

Is there a setup, please suggest.

I can any how see them by writing the below code -

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtGui import *
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import *
>>> for i in dir(QLabel):
...     print i
```

Comment: Probably not, what's wrong with `dir (QLabel)` anyway?

Comment: okay...that was quick and easy :) ....thanks anyway!!

Comment: Hey, I'm not 100% sure ;-) but I searched for a bit and couldn't find how to do what you want

Comment: maybe if we use a different IDE, it will work, not sure.

Comment: No, this is about python, the IDE doesn't matter

Comment: hmm..okay..thanks Tim!!